# How to install Cygwin with CLion?

Tags: c++, installation, ide, cygwin, clion

I've never set up an IDE before and I'm trying to setup CLion, as recommended by a friend for C++ development, however, I do not know which packets to install from Cygwin. I've tried to figure it out but there are many versions of each "make", "gcc", etc...

I'm trying to find out the basics in Cygwin that are required based upon this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/quickstart/

I just need help so I don't screw anything up with this new device that I'm using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267305/how-to-setup-clion-for-compile-and-run please check response by Rajat S